# What does the ARM LDRLE instruction do?

Tags: assembly, arm

I am inspecting some dissassembly with an LDRE instruction. e.g:

```
LDRLE R3, #0x1234
```

I can't find this in the instruction list. So my question is, what does the LDRLE instruction do?

My guess, if the instruction were represented by c code:

```
// LDRLE R3, #0x1234
R3 = R3 <= 0x1234 ? R3 : 0x1234
```

Comment: @MM - you have already (hastily?) accepted Bogwonch's answer, but please read my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LDRLE` instruction is really the LDR (load register from memory) instruction, with the conditional execution qualifer "LE" (less than or equal to).

The condition "LE" is "true" when the N flag and the V flag are different, and it's also true when the Z bit is set (Z, N and V are 3 of the 4 flag bits in the PSR).  You can find information from ARM on your processor's PSR layout.

So in other words, this `LDR` instruction is only executed when the "LE" condition is true per the current flags in the PSR.  These flags can be affected by instructions that execute *prior* to your `LDRLE` instruction.  In other words, the LE condition is evaluated based on the effects of *previous* instructions, not the values of the operands of the *current* instruction (in this case, the `LDRLE` instruction).

Finally, what does the instruction do if it is executed (condition LE is true per current PSR flags)?  It loads the (immediate) value 0x1234 into register R3.

Answer (score 0):

It loads the value in 0x1234 into R3 if the less than bit in the CPSR register is set.

in C: 
    if (LESS_THAN_BIT_SET) r3 = *(0x1234);

So if in a previous instruction you've set the less than or equal bit:

```
mov r0, #0
cmp r0, #1 ; equivalent to subs r0, r0, #1
```

Then any instruction with the LE conditional flag will be executed, else it'll be treated as a NOP.

Here's the manual page:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/Chdehgih.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and documentation!

Comment: There is some misleading/wrong information in this answer.  First, there is no "less than bit" (or LE conditional flag as you state later) in the CPSR.  "Less than or equal" (LE) is a condition whose boolean state is actually based on the values of multiple bits in the PSR ((Z==1) || (N!=V)).  Secondly, your C equivalent is incorrect - you are saying that R3 is loaded from memory address 0x1234 (register indirect), when really R3 is loaded with the immediate value 0x1234.  Please don't edit your answer since that would make this comment confusing.

Comment: By the way -- the last part of your answer is helpful / correct - if the condition is FALSE, the instruction isn't executed, and your URL which explains the mapping from conditions to PSR flag states is useful.

Answer (score 0):

The ARM ISA tries to expose the available hardware resources on every instruction, e.g. since there is a barrel shifter on the CPU, every instruction can shift/rotate one of its operands, and since there are condition codes on the CPU, every instruction can be executed conditionally.

So, an instruction on ARM assembly may be something like:

```
ADD[cond][S]
```

where `cond` is a condition encoded in two letters, allowing conditional execution, and `S` allows deciding whether the current instruction should affect condition codes (very useful combined with conditional execution).

Then, you will have to lookup the instruction using only the first part (`ADD` in this example).