# What does the 'bxpl' mean in ARM instruction

Tags: arm, instructions

I found '**bxpl**' in system call's implementation of Bionic C.
What's the difference between 'bx' and 'bxpl'?
BTW, I searched ARM's document, but found nothing, where should I go to look up info like this?

Please help, thanks.

```
/* autogenerated by gensyscalls.py */
#include <sys/linux-syscalls.h>

.text
.type read, #function
.globl read
.align 4
.fnstart

read:
.save   {r4, r7}
stmfd   sp!, {r4, r7}
ldr     r7, =__NR_read
swi     #0
ldmfd   sp!, {r4, r7}
movs    r0, r0
bxpl    lr
b       __set_syscall_errno
.fnend
```

=============================================

As @Notlikethat said
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1359731161338.html

Conditional PL = positive or zero

Comment: Did you read the bit about [condition codes](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1359731161338.html)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the ARM LDRLE instruction do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150039/what-does-the-arm-ldrle-instruction-do)

Comment: @Notlikethat, thanks a lot. Conditional PL = positive or zero.